# Create mirror table using fields of original table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some tables with a lot of columns that for every one of the table I have to create a "Mirror Table". This mirror contains the same columns of the original but there are bit type (except the Id). There isn't data to copy.

For example:

```
    Table_Original
    Id int
    Field1 varchar
    Field2 int
    Field3 bit
    ...
    Field50 varchar

    Table_Mirror
    Id [int] NOT NULL
    Field1 [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
    Field2 [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
    Field3 [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
    ...
    Field50 [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0))
```

Probably, in the future I have to replicate the process in other databases, so manually is not an (inteligent) option. What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Hhhhhmmm... are you using this to specify whether each field in the table is used or not?  Is there any reason why you are not using NULL for this purpose?

Comment: Nops, the mirror tables are used for other statistics reasons. And well, it's a "customer requeriment" so I can't change the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

Write an sql script with the appropriate `CREATE TABLE` commands and run this script via [`SQLCMD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).